# PCA and constructing an index

Tags: programming, index, pca, principal-components

Given a set of correlated securities and their corresponding closing prices, I am looking for a way to construct an index of these securities.

When applying PCA to obtain the principal components, how can I use or understand the output to construct an index?

For instance in matlab:

```
[coeff,score,latent,tsquared,explained,mu] = pca(prices)
```

Comment: Not sure I understood what you are trying to do. The eigenvector i from the PCA is in fact the weights of an index that would track the -ith principal component.

Comment: Hmm clear. But if you choose lets say the first two PC to explain the variation, how do you derive then the weight for the j-th asset?

Comment: I don't know. I would form a linear combination of the first two PC, weighted by the square roots of the respective eigenvalues (so the volatilities are properly taken into account).